# Keras LSTM Multiclass Classification structure

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am a beginner in machine learning and have been trying to use an LSTM to classify according to 12 features into 4 classes. I've followed quite a few tutorials but I'm still a bit confused. My dataset has 12 columns i want to use for training, including the label column which has the values that correspond to each class.

0 = Class 1

1 = Class 2

2 = Class 3

3 = Class 4

and this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import time
# For LSTM model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras import optimizers

# Load dataset
train = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\O\Documents\Datasets\FinalDataset2.csv")

train_proccessed = train.iloc[:, 1:13]

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(train_proccessed)

features_set = []
labels = []
for i in range(1, 393763):
    features_set.append(train_scaled[i-1:i, 0])
    labels.append(train_scaled[i, 0])

features_set, labels = np.array(features_set), np.array(labels)

features_set = np.reshape(features_set, (features_set.shape[0], features_set.shape[1], 1))


# Initialize LSTM model
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True,  activation='tanh', input_shape=(features_set.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
model.add(LSTM(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer = opt , loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(features_set, labels, epochs = 100, batch_size = 512)
```

I am very unsure about whether my model is built correctly or not. Moreover it only yields very low accuracies (27-28%). Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I've also tried a lot of different hyperparameters, just thought that's worth mentioning

Comment: I think its an issue with the way you derive the `features_set` and `labels`. Couldn't you just extract all the predictor variables and the target variables out from the dataframe?

Comment: Like I said I'm pretty new to machine learning haha. How would I go about doing that and how would it help?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

1. Last Layer to be Dense(4, activation='softmax')
2. Labels must be one hot encoded as you are using `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`

Here are more notes to help

1st Layer

```
LSTM(512, return_sequences=True,  activation='tanh')
```

- You started with huge LSTM units while your data is just 12 columns.
- `return_sequences=True` which is not justified in your case as you are not staking another layer after it

Model Body

- No layers in the middle between LST & final Dense()
- Add one Dense layer at least

Output Layer

- It could be easier to use loss as `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead of `categorical_crossentropy` so labels could be passes as numbers otherwise you need to one hot them

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Alright so I changed my return sequences to false, changed my LSTM layer to about 64 units, i have the LSTM layer followed instantly by the Dense layer. I used the sparse categorical crossentropy loss function, yet the accuracy is still consistently low, never more than 30%. Any idea what could still be wrong?

Comment: @OmarAttiaElSayedAttia Are you using processing Time Series or Text that needs LSTM? Or you it's picked as a layer to try?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to do is predict what class the data would be. Here's a link to a preview of the dataset since I can't post images, it should give you a better idea of what data I'm dealing with. The data is entirely numerical really:
[link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/804414884367827015/804426195566854264/143046241_232114275127561_8691875883319581638_n.png)

Comment: @OmarAttiaElSayedAttia based on sample, there is no sequence relation between them (Correct me, if I'm wrong) then no point to include LSTM. If order of your data has a meaning, then LSTM will make a difference

Comment: So for example, one of the relations is that according to the contents of the DLC & Data columns, so if the DLC is 8 and all of the data columns from 1-8 are 0, they would be classified to the first class. Does that make sense at all?